# Escaping slash and other characters when using JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, json

I did search on the internet but couldn't find a solution for me, this is the resulting JsonString when using Gson to convert my Object:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
String tmp;
tmp = gson.toJson(request);

{"_Json":"{LastName=ho, BirthDate=2017/10/06 08:47:29, FirstName=hey, Password=1, Email=letsgo}","_Token":"","_UserID":0}
```

Thats the actual Value I want to have in my JsonObject too but when I put this JsonString in my JsonObject the simple / are now / and I have no clue how I can get rid of this because I want to send this JsonObject via Post to create a user:

```
obj = new JSONObject(tmp);

{"_Json":"{LastName=ho, BirthDate=2017\/10\/06 08:47:29, FirstName=hey, Password=1, Email=letsgo}","_Token":"","_UserID":0}
```

I had a similar problem with gson when converting it in a JsonString but this simply solved by using:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: You could simply replace the escape characters

Comment: Do you know that value of `_Json` is not a valid json?

Comment: No I don't and I neither know how to replace them when already in JsonObject and it's meant to be a JsonObject (User) in the JsonObject HttpRequest